# MySQL Selecting Results using a wild card Not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, wildcard

Hi my table data look like this

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user_details
    -> ;
+----+----------+------+-----+
| ID | UserName | Type | Age |
+----+----------+------+-----+
|  2 | bandara  |    2 |  26 |
|  3 | panama   |    1 |  12 |
|  4 | sunil    |    2 | 100 |
|  5 | aaa      |    1 |  50 |
+----+----------+------+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

iI used a wildcard to select all recods starting from either b or p , but the result set is empty , what i am doing wrong here , please help , thanks in advance.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE UserName LIKE  '[bp]%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) :

```
SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE UserName REGEXP '^[bp]';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove bracket and put individual condition for `b` and `p` search tag like.

```
SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE UserName LIKE  'b%' OR UserName LIKE 'p%';
```

Comment: hi i tried this tutorial , is this not working for mysql http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: You are right this tutorial explain `SQL` query which is not for mysql

Comment: @ Sadikhasan he he , i never forget that , but still can not accept the answer , i gave you the upvote also :p

Answer (score 1):

Use code like this,

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE (UserName LIKE  'b%') OR (UserName LIKE 'p%');
```

Comment: hi i tried this tutorial , is this not working for mysql http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp